# QGIS 2.14.6 Delete Freehand Item

Tags: qgis, delete

I've created a freehand shape, but can't delete it. Screen shot attached. I can select it but the trash bin is grayed out, and the delete button prompts the error code "provider does not support delete". How do I get rid of this thing? Or do I have to delete and recreate the whole layer?

[image]

Comment: What's the layer data source?

Comment: The "Hazel" layer? No source, I just created a new layer and drew it freehand. Is that what you mean? @underdark

Comment: Unless you changed the default highlight color, none of the features in that screenshot are actually highlighted.

Comment: @csk the status bar notes that 2 features are selected on the layer.

Comment: @JamieSims you must have given a file name and probably a target folder. It might be that you don't have write permission on that folder. Change the folder to a place you have write permission.

Comment: I started again with this layer, it only had two objects in it anyway so wasn't a huge issue. I'll still be using freehand polygons in the future though, so a solution to their specific deletion would still be of interest.